# Combobox issue in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to set a combobox's value to the default one, the problem is the data source is from a query that return an integer type , I want my default value to be  "*", when I try this :

```
Private Sub LabelWklstID_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Me.WorklistIDSelector.Value = Mid(Me.WorklistIDSelector.DefaultValue, 2, 1)
End Sub
```

it didn't work getting " Invalid value " error, but when I try an int it works :

```
Me.WorklistIDSelector.Value = 1
```

How can I make my combobox accept the "*".  Any Help will be appreciated

Edit:

- RowSource=
  SELECT tWorkList.WorkListID, tWorkList.ProjectID FROM tWorkList GROUP BY tWorkList.WorkListID, tWorkList.ProjectID HAVING (((tWorkList.ProjectID)=[Forms]![fMain]![ProjectID])) ORDER BY tWorkList.WorkListID;
- Bound Column = 1
- Column Widths =2,54cm

Comment: You should clarify your question by adding to your question the RowSource, Bound column, and ColumnWidths of your combo. And by the way, you generally don't need VBA to define the default value of a control. That's a property of the control that you can set manually.

Comment: My purpose here not to define the default value but set the value of the combobox to the default or  simply set it to "*" (it is in event ), RowSource is a query (" SELECT tWorkList.WorkListID ...." WorkListID is an int)

Comment: Then `myControl.Value = myControl.DefaultValue` should do the trick !

Comment: Thank you @iDevlop, but it didn't, same error, Run-Time Error "2113":
 "The value you entered isn't valid for this field"

Comment: AGAIN: You should clarify your question by adding to your question the RowSource, Bound column, and ColumnWidths of your combo.

Answer (score 1):

select tworklistID as ID, other fields from tworlklist etc
UNION
select '*" as ID, 0,0,0(dummy blank other fields)